# R plot_ly: How display discrete & non-discrete data on same axis?

Tags: r, plotly

I am working on a stacked bar plot for the following data set, and get an error "Can't display both discrete & non-discrete data on same axis". Also, data is not plotted correctly. For each "month" on X-axis, I expect to have stacked bars by "unit" with values from "value".

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

df <- fread(
'"month","unit","value"
"2017-01","Unit 1",1064000
"2017-01","Unit 2",911487
"2017-02","Unit 1",851200
"2017-02","Unit 2",656640
"2017-03","Unit 1",834905
"2017-03","Unit 2",601920')

df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~month, y = ~value, type = 'bar', name = "month") %>% 
  add_trace(y = ~unit, name = "unit") %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Units by dates'), barmode = 'stack')
```

I will be highly appreciated if someone knows how to make workable plots here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to add a `trace` for a simple barplot it's easier to define a `color`-argument.

```
df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~month, y = ~value,  color = ~unit, type = "bar") %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Units by dates'), barmode = 'stack')
```

[image]